# Can you inject javascript into an ERB file?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, erb

I am working on a ruby sinatra app and wanted to know if it was possible to inject some javascript at the end of one my erb files from my routes.rb file. I have seen some ruby gems do this before but haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javascript in your .erb files like this:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('Hello world!');
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I don't want to write it directly into the erb file but instead write this in a ruby file append it to the end of the erb file just before it renders on the browser. I have seen gems do this before e.g. New Relic. This is so I can make it into a gem a use it in my other apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at how you can use `content_for` from rails and use it in your project: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for

I think you can grab this source of the method:

```
  def content_for(name, content = nil, options = {}, &block)
    if content || block_given?
      if block_given?
        options = content if content
        content = capture(&block)
      end
      if content
        options[:flush] ? @view_flow.set(name, content) : @view_flow.append(name, content)
      end
      nil
    else
      @view_flow.get(name).presence
    end
  end
```

Then use it like this:

**in your view:**

`<%= content_for :my_awesome_js %>`

**in .rb file:**

```
content_for :my_awesome_js do
  "<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('Hello world!');
    });
  </script>"
end
```